# Tem como criar regra no MYSQL para dividir o valor de uma coluna por outra?

Tags: mysql, query, select

Quero saber a média dos valores (valorm2) em uma tabela usando o AVG() (ou outra forma).

Tenho uma tabela no MYSQL com as colunas id, valortotal (Valor total), valorm2 (Valor por m²) e area.

Em algumas linhas o valorm2 está vazio e em outras o valortotal está vazio.

Tem alguma forma de fazer um select para se o campo estiver vazio, ele faça uma conta? Tipo o abaixo:

```
tabela_terrenos
id|valortotal|valorm2|area
1 |100000    | 1000  |100
2 |150000    |       |100
3 |          | 1500  |200
```

aí precisaria antes de trazer a média, algo do tipo:

```
SE valorm2 = vazio, então valorm2 = valortotal / area
SENÃO valorm2 = valorm2

SELECT AVG(valorm2)
FROM tabela_terrenos
```

Comment: a resposta abaixo resolveu o problema?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
SELECT IFNULL(AVG(valorm2), valortotal/area) valorm2
FROM tabela_terrenos
```